Asynchronous event-driven servlet in Tomcat 9 for long polling
I am looking for a best practice to implement the long polling in Tomcat 9, to enable sending messages from the server to the client by using the HTTPS protocol.
Using a synchronous I/O doesn't seem to be an efficient solution, because each connection produces a thread, so thousands of connected clients would produce thousands of threads.
Is there a way to create an asynchronous event-driven servlet in Tomcat 9, so all connections could be processed by a fixed thread pool?
I found the Comet API but it seems to be deprecated and not supported by Tomcat 9: HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL with comet processor
I know that WebSockets API is an alternative, but WebSockets uses a TCP port other than HTTPS which is not accepted by some of our clients (they only want to allow 443 port for the communication).

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere

@BasilBourque The Atmosphere library looks good, but I can't find any good examples of implementing servlets. There are AtmosphereServlet and MeteorServlet classes which apparently doing what I'm looking for. But I can't find any docs or examples of their usage.

WebSockets can be configured run on same port as HTTP(S). At least Tomcat by default does so.

I was able to create the long polling event-driven servlet based on Servlet API 3.0 and AsyncContext.
The pattern I used was the pub-sub pattern.
The entry in pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Servlet code:
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/rest/polling/*", asyncSupported = true)
public class LongPollingServlet extends HttpServlet {

    MessageProducer messageProducer = MessageProducer.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.setAttribute("org.apache.catalina.ASYNC_SUPPORTED", true);
        final AsyncContext asyncContext = req.startAsync();
        asyncContext.setTimeout(60*1000L);
        asyncContext.addListener(new AsyncListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                List<Message> messages = messageProducer.getMessages(event.getAsyncContext());
                
                resp.setStatus(200);
                // TODO Output messages to resp.getOutputStream() according to the client-server protocol
                
                messageProducer.unsubscribe(event.getAsyncContext());
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException { 
                // Here we do nothing, because timeout is followed by the onComplete call
                // which will return the empty message list to the client
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onError(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                pushSenderPolling.unsubscribe(event.getAsyncContext());
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
            }
        });
        
        String clientId = ...   // TODO Somehow get the client ID, for example from the request URL path
        messageProducer.subscribe(clientId, asyncContext);
    }
}

A data class storing the information about a client calling the long polling method, that is, a "subscribed" client:
public class OnlineClient {
    public String clientId;
    public AsyncContext context;
    public final List<Message> messages = new LinkedList<>();
    
    public MessageList(String clientId, AsyncContext context} {
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.context = context;
    }
}

Message producer code:
public class MessageProducer {

    // Singleton
    private MessageProducer _messageProducer = null;
    private MessageProducer() {}
    public MessageProducer getInstance() {
        if (_messageProducer == null) {
            _messageProducer = new MessageProducer();
        }
        return _messageProducer;
    }
    
    // Subscribed clients
    private Map<AsyncContext, OnlineClient> contextMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, OnlineClient> clientMap = new HashMap<>();
    
    public void subscribe(String clientId, AsyncContext context) {
        OnlineClient client = new OnlineClient(clientId, context);
        contextMap.put(context, client);
        clientMap.put(clientId, client);
    }
    
    public void unsubscribe(AsyncContext context) {
        OnlineClient client = contextMap.get(context);
        if (client != null) {
            clientMap.remove(context.clientId);
            contextMap.remove(context);
        }
    }
    
    public List<Message> getMessages(AsyncContext context) {
        OnlineClient client = contextMap.get(context);
        List<Message> result = new LinkedList<>();
        if (client != null) {
            synchronized (client.messages) {
                result.addAll(client.messages);
                client.messages.clear();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    // Called elsewhere when somebody wants to send a message
    public void publish(String clientId, Message message) {
        OnlineClient client = clientMap.get(clientId);
        if (client == null) {
            // Client is not subscribed
            // Here we can save the unsent message elsewhere or just do nothing
            return;
        }
        
        synchronized (client.messages) {
            client.messages.add(message);
        }
        // Notify the servlet processing thread and call onComplete()
        client.context.complete();
    }
}

